# Django Smart Select

Tags: python, django

I have been searching for a solution to what I thought would be a common request but have found very little while Googling. I am trying to create a 'cascading' set of dropdown menus, the normal sort of UI feature usually found in location forms where a user would select Country, City, Town etc.

The solution I have been trying to work with is https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects. However the documentation, what little there is of it, is quite confusing. Here are the models as I have them so far:

***models.py***

```
class InstrumentModelType(models.Model):
    model_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self.model_type)

class InstrumentManufactuer(models.Model):
    manufacturer_model_type = models.ForeignKey(InstrumentModelType)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self.manufacturer)

class InstrumentEquipmentType(models.Model):
    equipment_manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(InstrumentManufactuer)
    equipment_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
      return unicode(self.equipment_type)


class InstrumentDetails(models.Model):
    instrument_model_type = models.ForeignKey(InstrumentModelType)
    instrument_manufacturer = ChainedForeignKey(InstrumentManufactuer,
                            chained_field='instrument_model_type',
                            chained_model_field='manufacturer_model_type',
                            auto_choose = True,
                            show_all = False)
    instrument_equipment_type = ChainedForeignKey(InstrumentEquipmentType,
                          chained_field='instrument_manufacturer',
                          chained_model_field='equipment_manufacturer',
                          auto_choose = True,
                          show_all = False)

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.instrument_model_type, self.instrument_manufacturer, self.instrument_equipment_type)
```

When I choose an option from the first dropdown (instrument_model_type) neither of the other two dropdowns populate as expected. Ideally I want to be able to filter first by model type and then by manufacturer to show available equipment types. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

I have included the reference in `urls.py` as described in the docs and have tried numerous combinations of field references (chained_field/chained_model_field) to ensure I have understood the relations correctly. I also noticed that `simplejson` referenced in `widgets.py` has been depreciated so I replaced this with `json`.

While trawling the posts here I found http://www.dajaxproject.com/forms/ but the author on the Github page recommends not to use the library.

Am I wrong in thinking this is a common request? Is there a Django solution baked in that I have missed? If it matters at all I am using Django 1.6.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I just finished similar project and I guess your solution is:

```
class InstrumentEquipmentType(models.Model):
        manufacturer_model_type = models.ForeignKey(InstrumentModelType)
        instrument_manufacturer = ChainedForeignKey(InstrumentManufactuer,
                                chained_field='instrument_model_type',
                                chained_model_field='manufacturer_model_type',
                                auto_choose = True,
                                show_all = False)
        equipment_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
          return unicode(self.equipment_type)
```

Let me know if it did not work to send you my example

Answer (score 0):

Try Django Clever Selects

https://github.com/PragmaticMates/django-clever-selects

I use it in my Django 1.6 project. It is more usefull to operate chains in views and forms (in clever selects), not in models (like smart selects do).

Comment: Hi, Managed to shoe horn Clever-Selects into my project. It all works except when I submit the form I receive this: Data returned from ajax request (url=/tagnumbers/ajax/chained-brand-models/, params={'field_value': u'1', 'parent_value': u'1', 'field_name': 'manufacturer'}) could not be deserialized to Python object

Any ideas? Been trying to figure it out but had no luck so far. Thanks again

Comment: I had got something similar, and look for https://github.com/PragmaticMates/django-clever-selects/issues/6 hack. Just now clever-select working, but I'm not satisfied and looking forward.

Comment: Trying http://django-selectable.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html?highlight=chain#chained-selection